# Procedure does not work in a trigger. Without trigger, the system procedure works fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, xp-cmdshell

When I execute this procedure without a trigger, it all works fine

```
EXEC sys.XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "select * from users FOR JSON AUTO;" queryout E:\temp\JsonExport.json -t, -c -S . -d learntrigger -T'
```

but if I have created the trigger and make an `INSERT`, then I get no response from the server and I have to end the command manually

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER usersJosnExportTrigger  
ON users
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE   
AS  
    EXEC sys.XP_CMDSHELL 'bcp "select * from users FOR JSON AUTO;" queryout E:\temp\JsonExport.json -t, -c -S . -d learntrigger -T'
GO
```

This is the `INSERT` I use

```sql
INSERT INTO users (username, email, number) values  ('maxmuster','muster@gmail.com','123456789'),
```

I don't understand why and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Using `xp_cmdshell` in a trigger seems like a really bad idea in the first place. I wouldn't do this process as part of trigger at all. you would be better off designing a SP to do this, or creating a pooling table with the data to the extracted, and a regular running agent task.

Comment: Did you make a typo in the title? You seem to say it works in both places

Comment: The trigger runs in the context of the DML statement transaction that fired the trigger and the query run by BCP is a separate process, blocked by the uncommitted transaction. I suggest you heed the suggestion by @Larnu.